# Docker new user on host, how to let docker know?

Tags: docker

I created a new user on the host machine(Ubuntu) with a specific uid and started a container with a user in there that has the same user id.

Then mounted a folder that, on the host, this new user with that id has permissions on. Yet the user in the container, with a same id number, does not have them, while I would expect it them to have permission.

Turns out the user of the host isn't in the groups of the docker process(/proc/...)?

So, do I need to let the docker daemon know about the new user? Reload the docker daemon? Reload systemctl? Something else?

EDIT:

So, say my procId is 12345, I'm doing this:

`cat /proc/12345/status`

I'm seeing this:

```
Name:   process-inside-container
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   12345
Ngid:   0
Pid:    12345
PPid:   17847
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    20000   20000   20000   20000
Gid:    20000   20000   20000   20000
FDSize: 64
Groups: 145 
NStgid: 12345   30
...
```

So both inside and outside the container I created a user and group with id 20000. But as you can see from the "groups" parameters, only the old group with id 145 got recognized by the process. My host group with id 20000 hasn't been included. As such, I surmise, the permissions cannot be shared.

Or am I wrong as to what this means?

EDIT2: When I say I mounted a folder, it is via `docker run -v /data/:/data/`.

That folder is owned on the host by the user and group with id 20000, which is the id mentioned previously.

And for some reason, despite the user and group in the container having the same id, that user doesn't have permission to edit the folder.

EDIT3: I tried to `ls` the folder or `touch` a file in it and I got `Permission Denied`.

What eventually worked was changing the owner of the parent folder.

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? Can you show some terminal output?

Comment: @JohnKugelman example added

Comment: Could you also detail *that user doesn't have permission to edit the folder*? What did you try and what is the output?

Comment: @b0gusb Added. Was out for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

User inside the docker container is separate from host user. if you want your user inside docker container has uid and gid same as the one on the host, set it like below at the run time.

```
docker run -d --user <uid>:<gid> ubuntu:latest sleep infinity
```

more info [here](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf)

Comment: Example added to original post

Comment: Great, currently I'm at work, after that I will try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem, but hopefully this may clarify things a bit.

If inside the container you have a user with the same `uid` as some other user on the host, they both have the same rights on the mounted volume. This actually means that there is only one `uid` controlled by the kernel but with potentially different usernames (one for the host and another one for the container)

Create a user with `uid` `10002` on the host:

```
 sudo groupadd -g 10002 host_group1
 sudo useradd -r -u 10002 -g host_group1 host_user1
 sudo mkdir /vol1
 sudo chown -R host_user1 /vol1
```

Create an image and add user with name `container_user1` and the same `uid` (`10002`). The `Dockerfile`:

```
 FROM ubuntu:latest
 RUN groupadd -g 10002 container_group1
 RUN useradd -r -u 10002 -g container_group1 container_user1

 ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sleep", "infinity"]
```

Build the image:

```
docker build -t my-ubuntu .
```

Run the image with `/vol1` mounted volume:

```
 docker run -d -v /vol1:/vol1 --name my-ubuntu my-ubuntu
```

Check file permissions of both `host_user1` and `container_user1`

In the container as user `container_user1`

```
 su container-user1    
 echo aa >> /vol1/afile.txt
```

On the host write to the same file as user `host_user1`

```
 su host_user1
 echo bb >> /vol1/afile.txt
```

If you are in this situation then things should work out of the box. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I added an example to my original post.

Comment: When you say you mounted a folder I assume it's a docker volume shared between the container and the host machine.Is that right? If so what is exactly the problem you have with that volume?

Comment: The problem is that the user insde the container has no permissions on this volume. Despite being owned on host by a user and group with the same id.

Comment: I see. It would be useful if you could post the result of the `ls -an` command in `/data` from both host and container. In my opinion the configuration you have should work - there is something else missing or messing things up.

Comment: Output is identical from both host and container. A colleague told me it has to do with the fact that the group id is not in the groups of the `cat /proc/...` output. Not sure what that means.